theos tweak unable to read file when jailed
I'm not sure if I'm actually stupid or if iOS is playing tricks on me, I have a peculiar situation where my tweak is unable to read out a file using UIDocumentPicker

it works in a jailbroken environment
a different tweak that is injected alongside mine has no issues reading a plist file on a jailed device
mine seems to be unable to read a plist on the jailed device although the other tweak can
exporting a plist works in both environments

so I really dunno what the deal is there, am I just missing something or how is it that my tweak is the odd one out
Implementation: https://github.com/castdrian/Gonerino/blob/main/Settings.x#L270-L298
Tweak that can read files perfectly fine while jailed:
https://github.com/dayanch96/YTLite/releases/tag/v5.0.2
genuinely stumped, importing the plist works fine in that tweak's settings whilst injected alongside mine, so dunno what black sideloading magic is going on there
I tried to dissect the other tweaks dylib to see if there are somehow entitlements there or anything that my tweak is somehow missing, but also rather unfortunately the parts that do the plist import/export for that tweak are not open source
